# Helicity Problem

Tags: quantum-field-theory, angular-momentum, helicity

I have the following task and I have no idea how to start.

To do: The angular momentum of the radiation field is given by $$ J = \int x \wedge (E \wedge B) d^3x $$
Define the corresponding operator.

I have no idea what a corresponding operator is or what I have to do. Hopefully you can help me, thanks :)

Comment: [Poynting vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poynting_vector).

Comment: I read the article and other literature, but I don't know what I have to do. Can you explain it more detailed, please.